# Am I using these global variables correctly?

Tags: php

I'm a newbie to php, and I'm in the process of *hacking through* some moodle code for a prototype.

Anyhows I have some data Id like passed from file1.php to file2.php, for which Im using global variables. The values are  intialized in file2 and I need them for use in file1. Here's how I go about it

file1.php

```
 <?php// top of file 1

 global $content; // discussion content // line 3
```

file2.php

```
global $content;// line 3379

  $content=$post->subject;
```

Back in file1.php

```
   echo 'global scope'.$content; // this is always empty// line 168
```

Am I missing something here?
Attached files [file1.php](http://pastebin.com/JJHupyhm) and [file2.php](http://pastebin.com/CWApGGZa)

Comment: No. That's not right. Each PHP script is own little universe, and variables set in one will **NOT** be visible to the other on the next request. You need to use sessions or other means of persisting the data.

Comment: Nope you are not using the `global` keyword correctly. You probably meant to do `// global`.

Comment: lol PeeHaa! I read that as comment out global cause it is a rancid death trap. I don't know if OP is including files or what. But I agree with you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use global to get a global variable

```
//file 1
$a = "im a global variable";

function foo(){
    global $a;
    echo $a;
}

//file 2
require "file1.php";

function foo2(){
    global $a;
    echo $a;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. And Im marking it as accepted because it works in the general case. However, I dont think moodle allows user defined globals :(

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing a thought,

suppose in file1, you have $content = "myID";

and in file2, if you include("file1.php"), you can access by doing,

```
global $content;
var_dump($content) will output string 'myId' (length=4)
```